# Client-side XSLT with Jersey 2.0

Tags: java, xml, rest, xslt, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to transform XML file to HTML using client-side XSLT.

I'm using Jersey 2.0.1, Java 7 and Tomcat 7

the xml file and xsl files are under src/main/resrouces

Here is my REST resource code:

```
@GET
@Produces({ "application/xml" })
@XmlHeader(value = "<?xml-stylesheet type='application/xml' href='project-info.xsl' ?>")
public ProjectListType getProjectListType() throws JAXBException,
        ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
        TransformerException {
    URL fileUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("project-info.xml");

    ProjectListType result = new ProjectInfoUnmarshaller().unmarshall(new File(
            fileUrl.getPath()));

    return result;
}
```

The xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Projects info</h2>
            <xsl:template match="projectListType">
                <table border="1" cellpading="6" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#4bbd92">
                        <th>Project Name</th>
                        <th>Product Owner</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="project">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="projectName" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="pointOfContact" />
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:template>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

And the xml I am testing with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectListType>
<project>
    <projectName>proj1</projectName>
    <pointOfContact>John Doe</pointOfContact>
</project>
    <project>
    <projectName>proj2</projectName>
    <pointOfContact>Jon Smith</pointOfContact>
</project>
```

The output of the REST resource in the browser is single line of text containing the text between the tags of the xml file. I want to display html formatted output with the same content.
I think there is something wrong with the server-side code, because when I test it in isolation (simply open the xml same file including the xslt in a browser) it works as expected.

Do you have any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Is the stylesheet itself definitely being served correctly from the right URL (the `href` you've used will be treated as a relative URL and resolved by the browser against the location of the REST resource)?

Comment: What's the benefit in using client side XSLT when your server is perfectly capable of doing that? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: Ian, you are right! I need to deploy the stylesheet so that the browser sees it when it loads the stylesheet. Thank you!

Comment: Tomalak, I prefer the client side XSLT because of the separation of concerns it provides. In my case the content I am displaying is 100% static and I don't want the server process/transform this content - just send it as it is and let the browser deal with the exact UI visualizations.